# nCover + MSTest + CruiseControl = Zero Coverage

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, mstest, ncover

I use CruiseControl.net, MSTest 3.5 and nCover 1.5.8.
I am new to nCover and want to integrate it in CruiseControl.

The problem is that I get a 0% coverage result but it should be 100%.
My demo app calls just one method and in my mstest project this method is tested. in my cruiseControl server all works fine without ncover and i can see the mstest results (passes with ok)

now i want to through in nCover.
in my cruiseConttrol server I call a nant script that does this (simplified):

```
<target name="nCover">
  <exec program="C:\Programme\NCover\ncover.console.exe" 
       workingdir="C:\temp" 
       commandline="//a CCTestApp //x coverage.xml C:\MSTest.exe /testcontainer:UnitTests.dll /resultsfile:mstestResult.trx /nologo" />
</target>
```

Running this in cruisecontrol seems to work and i can see the ncover result. but the result is 0% coverage

any ideas?

bye bembi

Comment: I haven't noticed this problem in NCover recent versions

Answer (score 3):

I got it!

If using MSTest you have to set the /noisolation flag for mstest in order to get it working!
this flag prevents mstest from starting another thread which ncover can't handle.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the //coverall flag on NCover, which will allow it to handle process isolation under MSTest.

Comment: //coverall isn't avaliable for ncover 1.5.8